# Suitable CSS display for showing 3 items in each row with arbitrary number of rows?

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, grid

I have a list of items that I wish to display. At first I used [`display: flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) but noticed that when the line wrap occurred, the items weren't aligned horizontally. Then I switched to [`display: grid`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) but that requires me to know the number of rows in advance.

What kind of display is suitable for creating a grid of arbitrary many items with *n* items in each row?

```
<div class="element">
  <app-check *ngFor="let item of items" [caption]="item.name">
  </app-check>
</div>

div.elements {
  display: ???; ...
}

app-check {
  flex: 1 1 auto; ... ???
}
```

The above CSS would work if I somehow could push out the items three-by-three. I can do that using some logic in the component code but it seems like an ugly hack. And I prefer to resolve it in an appropriate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3 items you can do it in a similar way, just use flex-basis: 33% for the child element:

```css
div.element {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

app-check {
    flex: 1 0 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
    <app-check *ngFor="let item of items" [caption]="item.name">
    </app-check>
</div>
```

This is a good place to study flexbox:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Ahem... Did you suggest a link to the same page as I linked to in my question? I don't fully understand. Please elaborate?

Comment: Yes sorry, I haven't seen your link before, but still, if you want to show 3 itens per row, the code I've posted should work.

Comment: I see. I suspected that was the case but didn't want to arrogantly assume anything in case there's a point I'm missing. As for your suggestion - yes'ish - it works almost perfectly. The thing I had to change was the *grow* of the flex to 0. Otherwise, the content got split after 3 elements as requested **but** the last line had a different horizontal spread causing the elements not to align vertically. Your answer is accepted, since it - obviously - resolved my issue. Thanks!